# How to Fix, AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_img'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm very new to coding and was coping this code from a youtube video I saw subbing in my own files for images when necessary. I got to the final step of testing the ai on new images and getting a result but this error message pops up.

dir_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/darth_vader_Bing_images/test 1"

```
for i in os.listdir(dir_path ):
    image = img.load_img(dir_path+'//'+ i)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show
```

Comment: You should provide enough code so that we know what `img` is. I can only guess and say that `img` is `JpegImageFile` class from `PIL`. In most cases it would be also beneficial to provide a full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

**Sample code**

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = Image.open('cat1.jpeg')
plt.imshow(img)
```